# It´s possible to configure RabbitMQ to notify consumer after receiving n messages?

Tags: rabbitmq, message, consumer, publisher

I have a doubt, I need to know if it´s possible to configure RabbitMQ to notify consumer after receiving n messages.

Example: The RabbitMQ must only notify the consumer after it receive 100 message.

If not, what would be the best approach.

Best regards.

Jolynice

Comment: Actually no , since the broker is designed with the view of notifying a consumer anytime a message is available . You may however want to process messages in batches and only triggering the next notification when the current set of messages are acknowledged in which case you should look at setting the prefetch count for the consumer https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html

Comment: Hello Soumen Mukherjee. Thank you very much for the reply. I will check the prefetch count approach. Best regards.